# Dropdown Z-index not responding

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, z-index

The dropdown menu which appears when you click "Choose Category" displays at a z-index below the content below it. I've tried changing the z-index of the ul and li but doesn't respond.

What might be the cause of this and what might be a solution?

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: do not post links to external websites like this, if you have code that needs to be seen put it here, external links go dead. also nobody wants to click on links that may or may not be dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simple just give `.utility-bar` class to `z-index:1`.

Because both `UL` have `position:absolute` So, give it's container `z-index` value higher than other will solve your issue.

**Note:** And take care of next time. Do not post link, post Actual code here in question. Otherwise it is consider as low-quality post.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read up on how to post on this website.